# Deploying the repo (yarn start)

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, vercel, netlify

The package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "weather-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "tailwind dev": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/css/input.css -o ./public/css/style.css --watch",
    "tailwind build": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/css/input.css -o ./public/css/style.css --minify",
    "workbox build": "npx workbox-cli generateSW workbox-config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "alpinejs": "^3.12.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "browserslist": "^4.21.5",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001481",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-minify": "^1.0.0",
    "helmet": "^6.0.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "moment-recur": "^1.0.7",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "pwa-asset-generator": "^6.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.35.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-xo": "^0.43.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  }
}
```

In one service where I deploy the repo everything works fine. This are the command which are in it:

- Branch: public
- Runtime: Node
- Build Command: yarn
- Start Command: yarn start

I click "Deploy" and everything works fine.

But when I want to deploy the same repo for example in Netlify, Vercel, Cloudflare there are no such settings like wrote above. There are only Build configurations for example in Vercel like:

- Framework preset:
- Build Command:
- Output Directory:
- Install Command:

And I write like this:

- Framework preset:
- Build Command: yarn
- Output Directory: public
- Install Command:

and it's not working.

How to write this command to the Vercel or Netlify or Cloudflare services to works correctly? Should I write something more in package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

For vercel, you can just connect your git repository and define a production branch. When you will push on this branch, the CD will deploy your app in production.
You can also use the vercel CLI : `vercel deploy`

Reading your package.json, I saw the `build` script is missing. Maybe add a build script that build tailwind and workbox like this:
`"build": "npm run tailwind_build && npm run workbox_build" //for npm, idk for yarn.`